# How can i add images in source folder of a Maven Java Project?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have images in source folder of a maven java project. you can see it in the below image.

[image: images in source folder]

if i run install command of maven, when i see generated jar file , i could not see the images in sources in the jar file.

My maven configuration is like below.

```
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass></mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

How can i add images in source folder to jar file for my maven java project ?

Comment: Place the Images in `src/main/resources/opazyazilim/icons2`. After compilation they then reside with `IconManager.class`.

Comment: so isnt there any way to add files other than source java files in src/main folder to generated jar by maven ?

Comment: There should be in the jar `/opazyazilim/icons2/16attach.png`.  By strong convention `src/main/resources/` is the root for resource files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [resources plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html) to add those files into your JAR. By default, Maven will look for your project's resources under `src/main/resources`. So if you move your images there, they should be automatically included. However, if you want to include a different folder, you can tell Maven with:

```
<project>
 ...
 <build>
   ...
   <resources>
     <resource>
       <directory>[your folder here]</directory>
       <includes><include>*.png</include></includes>
     </resource>
   </resources>
   ...
 </build>
 ...
</project>
```

Comment: Many thanks. It helped to some extent. This picked up all images from location _[your folder here]_ but put them in root of jar. How to specify target location?