# Scanner cannot find (correct) file path

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

I'm programming in Java with IntelliJ and have been trying to use the Scanner class to read the file. Even with the correct path, I still get a "No such file or directory" error.  Does anyone have any suggestions?
My working directory is /Users/kevinliu/Desktop/test
[Here is a picture of how the project is set-up.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EstZr.png)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create a swing/console application using maven? 
If yes, maven is not able to find the source. You have to add it on the pom file. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45751561/how-can-i-add-images-in-source-folder-of-a-maven-java-project) on how to add it on pom file.

if no, do you have rights to access the address of the image file? Some times, folder are protected by the OS.

You can also use `YourClassName.class.getResource("input/input1.txt")` to locate file/s under the directory that your class was in.

Answer (score 0):

> Even with the correct path, I still get a "No such file or directory" error.

The path is *NOT* correct.  That path says look for a directory called "src" in the root directory of your computer.  That is almost certainly not where the input file lives.

If you are going to use an absolute pathname for a file within the working directory that you stated, it should look like this:

```
  /Users/kevinliu/Desktop/test/src/input/input1.txt
```

(You can check what it will actually be using a file browser ... outside of Intellij.)

If you want to use a relative pathname, try this

```
  src/input/input1.txt
```

Notes:

1. There is no leading "/" on a relative pathname.  A leading "/" means it is an absolute pathname.  Absolute pathnames *start* at the root directory.
2. A relative path is resolved relative to the `>>current<<` working directory.  That will depend on where and how you run the application ...
3. For a production application, you would not want to refer to a file in the source tree.  The end user typically won't have the source tree.
4. Consider making the path a command line argument or configuration setting for your application.
5. Consider making the file a "resource" that is part of the application's JAR file.  (You would open it a different way ...)
6. If you ever get a "No such file or directory" message, that means that the path is not correct in some sense.  You might be in the wrong place, you might not have permission on a parent directory, the file may have been removed or renamed, there may be a you, or something else.  Either way, that error comes from the operating system and the OS doesn't make mistakes about these things.  The mistake will be yours (or the user's).